# Finding Norton's equivalent circuit

Tags: thevenin

I need to find Norton's equivalent for the following circuit:

[image: originally posted as http://i57.tinypic.com/24o29fq.jpg]

Why can't I just take the open-circuit voltage and the short circuit current, divide voltage over current and thus obtain the equivalent resistance? My textbook gives no explanation at all.

(I tagged [thevenin](/questions/tagged/thevenin) because there isn't a [norton](/questions/tagged/norton) tag)

Open circuit voltage:

\$\ 10-3*i_a+2*i_a-6*i_a=0  \$

\$\ V_o=6*10/7 \$ volts

Short cirtuit current:

\$\ 10-3*i_s-5*i_s=0\$

\$\ i_s=10/ 8\$ amps

This is apparently wrong.

Comment: Edit: Image fixed :))

Comment: If 2Ia flows towards a 5 ohm (which is open circuit) and a 6 ohm, how can the current thru the 6 ohm be only Ia?

Comment: I'm sorry for my terrible drawing, that's a dependent voltage source not current 2ia!

Comment: If you want people to discuss your circuit, please name/label the *&^%$ components and nodes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your short-circuit current calculation assumes that the current through the 3 ohm resistor is the same as that through the 5 ohm resistor, and that Ia is zero.  You should write an equation for KCL at the junction of the 5 ohm and 6 ohm, and an equation for the voltage at that same node. Solve, etc.

Comment: Ahh yeah, such a stupid mistake! Problem solved, thank you.

Comment: What answer did you get, and does it agree with the book?

Comment: I don't remember now but it agreed with the book! :)